# Selenium Firefox Webdriver - need help locating button and with code to click button

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I'm using Selenium and need to click on a button called Income Statement at http://www.tradingview.com/screener.  Could anyone help me to find the button name and let me know if the code where I'm trying to implement it is correct.  Any help much appreciated.  Thanks!!

```
url = 'http://www.tradingview.com/screener'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

button_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='Income Statement']")
button_element.click()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems here:

1. You have to add wait / delay before accessing that element.
   This should preferably be done by expected conditions explicit waits.
2. You are using a wrong locator.

This should work better:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = 'http://www.tradingview.com/screener'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get(url)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-set='income_statement']"))).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath does not locate the right element in the HTMLDOM.

so instead of this:

```
//input[@name='Income Statement']
```

use this:

```
//div[@data-set='income_statement']
```

or

a **CSS** like this:

```
div[data-set = 'income_statement']
```

**explanation:**

See this is a **outerHTML**:

```
<div class="tv-screener-toolbar__favorites-item js-favorite-item" data-set="income_statement">
                    Income Statement
                </div>
```

As we can see it is a `div tag`, so we are using `//div` and also it has `data-set` attribute `income_statement` and when you write the XPath, it is able to locate the right node with `1/1` uniqueness.

Also It's a best practise to use **ExplicitWait:**

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
try:
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-set='income_statement']"))).click()
    print('Clicked on the button')
except:
    print('Could not click ')
    pass
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```